# how to auth sidekiq in a rails api with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

We added a sidkiq Ui to a rails api with devise, we have admin views for login which are currently working but sidkiq auth is not working

> authenticate :admin do
> mount Sidekiq::Web => "/admins/sidekiq"
> end

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "auth is not working"? Do you get an error? Or maybe any user can access this page?

Comment: Which versions of rails and devise are you using?